# How do I send a controller with datetime control control in Ajax?

Tags: c#, ajax, model-view-controller

I'm using MVC in a project with a DateTimePicker I need to get the year history and send it to the controllers via ajax. How can I do this with ajax when datetimepicker date selection is done?

Comment: Pass the currently selected date/time in the AJAX call (could be a form field, could be a URL query parameter), then display the returned data. But there are huge possible variation in the details.

Comment: with an example?

Comment: @Emrecan You didn't provide any code. An example would be writing the code for you. Try to include a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: With @ Ajax.ActionLink I can send data to control and do related operations. The year value is required for these operations to be performed. I can not get the year value only from the datetimepicker.